# Issue with Google API looping info windows

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, loops, google-api

Having an issue with the code below.. Google map markers are displaying fine, but associated info windows are not displaying on click. On click, no action is taking place. Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
var length = data[0].length;

var infowindow = [];
var contentString = [];
var marker = [];

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

    var x = data[0][i].number;

    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(data[0][i].lat, data[0][i].long);

    marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/' + data[0][i].color + '-dot.png',
        description: data[0][i].providerfirst,
        id: i
    });

    //document.write(marker[i].icon);


    contentString[i] = '<div id="content" class="infowindow">' +
        '<div id="siteNotice">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"> ' + data[0][i].providerfirst + ' ' +
        data[0][i].providerlast + ', ' + data[0][i].credentials + '</h1>' +
        '<p>' +
        data[0][i].address + '<br>' +
        data[0][i].city + ', ' + data[0][i].state + ', ' + data[0][i].zip + '<br>' +
        '</p>' +
        '<p>NPI: ' + data[0][i].npi + '</p>' +
        '<p>Network: ' + data[0][i].type + '</p>' +
        '<div id="bodyContent">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    //document.write(contentString[i]);


    //document.write(infowindow[i].content);

    infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString[i]
    })

}
```

Comment: You don't have any event listener for the click on the marker.

Answer (score 0):

u need to put

```
contentString[i]  = '<div id="content" class="infowindow">' +
                      '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"> ' + data[0][i].providerfirst + ' ' + 
                      data[0][i].providerlast + ', ' + data[0][i].credentials + '</h1>' +
                      '<p>' + 
                      data[0][i].address + '<br>' +
                      data[0][i].city + ', ' + data[0][i].state + ', ' + data[0][i].zip + '<br>' +
                      '</p>' +
                      '<p>NPI: ' + data[0][i].npi + '</p>' +  
                      '<p>Network: ' + data[0][i].type + '</p>' +
                      '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '</div>';

                      //document.write(contentString[i]);


                    //document.write(infowindow[i].content);

                  infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString[i]})
```

this part of code in a function like

```
function setInfoWindow(i){
//all this here
}
```

U need to understand javascript concepts 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am getting the exact same behavior with the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need a click handler, just because you created the infowindow and the data, you haven't associated them in any way that I can see

```
marker[i].addListener('click',function(){
    infowindow[i].open(map,marker[i]);
});
```